# import data of models.py with 2 class into template

Tags: python, django

I am a amature django developer. I have a model with two class called "Post" and "Catagory". I want to read Category items in my template. How can I import my category in my template and show it's data in my page?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Post (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = TaggableManager ()
    cats = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.title
```

Thank you.

Comment: So you want db value to print into template right ?

Comment: You need a view. Where is your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using class based views and want to list all categories you could do:

```
# urls.py
url(regex=r'^category/$',
    view=CategoriesListView.as_view(),
    name='category_list_all'),

# views.py
class CategoriesListView(ListView):
    model = Category

# category_list.html
<h2>Category list</h2>

<ul>
  {% for cat in category_list %}
  <li>
      {{ cat.category }}
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You would place the html file in `<project_route>/<app_name>/templates/<app_name>/` or `<project_route>/templates/<app_name>/`

If you have an existing function based view that's working with the Post model then you can just do something like:

```
# views.py
...
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pass_in_pk)
return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post})

# post.html
<h2>Category list</h2>

<ul>
  {% for category in post.cats %}
  <li>{{ category.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

If you have a class based view based on a Post model using the DetailView then you can also use the above html, just place it in `post_detail.html` in the appropriate folder.

Answer (score 0):

It`s like get the category value and assign into settings and passed into view html will work

```
def viewfuncion(request):

    template_vars = {}
    settings = Category.objects.get(pk=1)
    template_vars['title_show'] = settings.title
    t = loader.get_template('view.html')
    c = Context(template_vars)

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c), content_type = "application/xhtml")
```

So in your HTML { title_show } will print the content